# How to display names instead of id's in GridView Yii2?

Tags: yii2

I have a question here. I set the relations between `item` and `sale` tables and now my `GridView` column of `Item name` is displaying `id's` of it. But what I need is that it would display `Item names` instead of `ID's`. How should I do that?

Here is my `GridView column`:

```
[
     'attribute' => 'item_id',
      'value' => 
],
```

I was thinking that I should write a function with `if` statement, but I have a lot of names and it would be very long. Is there an easier way to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your relationship is called `getItems()`, and the field for the item's name is called `name`:

```
[
     'attribute' => 'items.name'
],
```

Comment: Oh god, that was so easy.. Thank you, gmc!

Answer (score 2):

In my case it is company table and products table.
    `comp_id` is is the primary key in the company table and it has related with products table.

```
<?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

            'prod_id',
            'name',
            'description:ntext',
            [
                'attribute' => 'comp_id',
                'value'     => 'comp.name' //getComp()
            ],

            ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
        ],
    ]); ?> 

//getcomp function the product model page.
 public function getComp()
    {`enter code here`
        return $this->hasOne(Company::className(), ['comp_id' => 'comp_id']);
    }
```